# Can't upload audio file with PHP5.5.12 on WampServer 2.5

Tags: php

I have a problem with upload mode in PHP. Can you help me ?
My form in HTML:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

My PHP code in `'upload_file.php'`:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_FILES['file'])){
    echo "Failed";
}
else{
    echo "All Ok";
}
?>
```

When I select `image`, `text`, `zip`, `rar` ... It report **"All Ok"**. But, If I select `audio` or `video`, it report **"Failed"**. So I can't upload audio file. What is wrong ? Thank you very much !.

Comment: Can you make sure that your uploaded file does not exceed any limitation? Check `phpinfo()` for more information.

Comment: Thanks very much! In php.ini, post_max_size only 3M so I can't upload. I fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear! I converted the comment to answer, so your issue is solved, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the size of your file does not exceed the limitations listed here (your `php.ini` file)

```
# The values are just for example! 

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 3M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 3M
```